# Set focus on input text where ID not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus

I want to set focus each time on the textbox if alert message is prompted. How should I deal where I use that javascript function for multiple times. Here is my js code

```
function validateLandline(landfield) {
        var reg = /\d{5}([- ]*)\d{6}/;            
        if (reg.test(landfield.value) == false) {
            jAlert('Kindly enter valid landline no', 'INFORMATION');
            return false;
            landfield.focus();
        }
        return true;
    }
```

and textbox html

```
<input type="text" id="txtStoreSiteL1" onchange="validateLandline(this);" maxlength="20" />
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "use that JavaScript function multiple times"? And secondly, you should have `landfield.focus();` followed by `return false;`

Comment: @MilanChheda: See, I have multiple textboxes to set focus and one common function for validating it. So is the process which I am doing is correct or not ?.

Comment: Well, yes, your code is correct. but in case of multiple textboxes, it would end up focusing on last textbox.

Comment: @MilanChheda: yes, but the validation is also not working. SO any other way to do this ? let me know

Comment: So What are you trying to validate with the regular expression?

Comment: @MilanChheda: I want to check whether user has entered valid email id or not. if entered valid id is not correct then set focus on that textbox

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158830/discussion-between-vvvv-and-milan-chheda).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, I have created a small snippet below:

```js
function validateEmail($email) {
  var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
  return emailReg.test($email);
}

$('input').on('input focusout', function() {
  $(this).removeClass('error');
  if (!validateEmail($(this).val())) {
    $(this).addClass('error').focus();
  }
});
```

```css
.error {
  border: 2px solid #d00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtStoreSiteL1" maxlength="20" />
<input type="text" id="txtStoreSiteL2" maxlength="20" />
```

Comment: even if I enter the wrong email id, i am able to move my mouse to next textbox. this is not what I want mate.. :)

Comment: Okay, I updated the code. I thought adding red borders as indicator would be enough :)

Comment: where have you called the function `validateEmail()`, but still your code is working on snippet ?

Comment: I have called `validateEmail()` on `input` and `focusout` event. So the code won't allow user to move to next field unless first field is successfully validated. You can try the above snippet.

Comment: hi can u come on chat